# 90's talking computer children's tv science fiction series

Tags: tv, story-identification

In the early 90's, when I was a child, I regularly saw a live-action (not animated) TV show with children that did something good (solve problems or chase away bad guys, I'm not sure). It was on Dutch television, but I think the show was not originally Dutch.

The thing I was most impressed with and remember most vividly is their computer. They had a big talking computer screen that could show all kinds of stuff in green-on-black on it. I also remember a lens of some sort mounted somewhere around the screen that would be the computer's eye. The computer had a slot into which data sticks could be inserted.

I *think* the computer may have been in a barn, but that sounds silly and I'm not sure.

None of my search attempts have yielded any results. Does anyone know the name of this show?

The name may have included `Mission`, but I keep thinking about Mission Impossible, and that's obviously not the show I meant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The show you're thinking of is [Mission Top Secret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Top_Secret). An Australian kids spy show, I remember it, and the books very well.

> This Australian TV series is about an organization known as the Centauri Network, it is a network of children from around the planet who fight crime, & solve mysteries with the help of gadgets, which were quite advanced for the time.

Comment: Haha, yes! I recognize the [opening sequence](http://youtu.be/dmICXl6VpPc). However, I could not find any footage of the computer (screen).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't remember a Data slot, and it's VERY old (from my childhood, and I'm 41), but what you are describing has a lot in common with '[Read All About It!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read_All_About_It!)'.  Otto & Theta (intelligent computers; Theta is the talking monitor, Otto is a printer), it takes place in a Coach House, the kids do various good things, etc.  And it was on PBS.

Does this look at all familiar:
[image: Otto & Theta]

If so, take a look [here](http://www.rickstv.com/tvo/read.html); that may confirm it with more info and images.

This is a bit of a stretch, timewise, but since it was originally in English, it may have shown on Dutch Television years later.

Comment: Dunno how long it will stay up, but [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pg9lLi_I60) a video link to the first episode.  VERY low quality, but it might help to confirm things.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is also not what I was looking for. I remember the screen being a whole lot bigger (the size of a small wall). It seems that this show is for a little bit younger children than how I remember my show.

Comment: No problem; that's why we toss out ideas -- The more of us that get it wrong, the better a chance someone else has of getting it right. :)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the 90s version of [The Tomorrow People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tomorrow_People#1990s_series)?

Comment: My search also turned up The Tomorrow People, but it is in no way familiar. It can't be it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean? *Children of the Dog Star*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it’s [*Crash Zone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crash_Zone). I remember watching it on Saturday Disney early 90s. Back when shelley was hosting

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please explain why you think this is the answer (e.g. by listing some aspects that match the description in the question), especially since a different answer has already been accepted.